# Insert data to a custom content type by using webform in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

I have a custom content type and respect to that I have designed a Webform for normal user. But I want to inset the data of the Webform to my custom content type and display it using view. Display a custom content type in View is know to me but I want to insert data of Webform to the custom content. Is that possible. Is there any other way where I can use a custom form to insert data in a content type. I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use views to render the results of the form,
and then adding the view results to the custom node using views [node field module](https://drupal.org/project/viewsnodefield).

You will need to create a new view, in the 'Show' box choose 'webform submissions'
Create the view and add it as a **custom field** in your custom content type.

Answer (score 0):

I do this task using [webform Rules](https://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) - create a rule "on submit" event, in which create a new node using the data from the submission, and then redirect to wherever you want.

Hope this helps,
Shushu